# Открыть страницу в браузере и перейти по ссылке

Tags: vbscript, браузер

Нужно открыть браузер, перейти на определенную страницу (www.site.com), затем найти определенную ссылку (www.site.com/*link.html) и перейти по той ссылке именно со страницы сайта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли такое осуществить посредством VBScript? Подойдут любые варианты.

Comment: Что значит со страницы сайта? Чем открытие ссылки в отдельном окне браузера отличается от открытия ссылки по клику при посещении сайта? Какие-то данные собираются?

Answer (score 1):

Открыть браузер и перейти по ссылке можно так:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

iURL = "www.google.com"

Call objShell.ShellExecute("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1)
```

Предварительно вы можете скачать страницу и найти нужную вам ссылку.

Comment: А как теперь зделать чтоб этот браузер открылся в скрытом режиме???

Answer (score 0):

```
If MsgBox("Открыть google.com?", 4, "Открытие сайта") = 6 Then 
    SET vsh = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
    vsh.run "https://google.com"
End if
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]